# Vue 3 TypeScript - Property 'searchData' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

im trying to use function as a computed value in defineComponent:
[code printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGlzX.png)

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import { testData } from "../assets/testData";


export type SearchDataType = {
  _id: string;
  index: number;
  name: string;
};

interface ISearchPage {
  searchData: SearchDataType[];
  searchQuery: string
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: "SearchPage",
  components: {},
  data(): ISearchPage {
    return {
      searchData: [],
      searchQuery: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getData: function () {
      this.searchData = testData;
    },
  },
  created(){
    this.getData()
  },
  computed: {
    filteredSearch: function() {
      
      return this.searchData.filter((filteredItem: SearchDataType) => {
        return filteredItem.name.match(this.searchQuery)
      })
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

And, when i want to use **this.searchData** variable in computed im reciving the following errors:

```
Property 'searchData' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{ [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 10 more ..., {}>'.
  Property 'searchData' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: { [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }; ... 10 more ...; $watch(source: string | Function, cb: Function, options?: WatchOptions<...> | undefined): WatchStopHandle; } & ... 4 more ... & Co...'
```

I was trying to add the code below to shims-vue.d.ts file, but it didn't solve the problem:

```
import { ComponentCustomProperties } from "vue";

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
  interface CreateComponentPublicInstance {
    searchData: any | null;
  }
}
```

Im new to vue with TypeScript. Could someone tell me, what am doing wrong?